# jquery hidden element loading for 1 second on page load

Tags: jquery, load

I am using a jquery slide in slide out that appears on the page when loading (about 1 second) then is hidden. I dont want it to show at all, how can i do this?

I am using this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
 // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
 // (a little sooner than page load)
  $('#menucategory').hide();
 // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link
  $('img.menu_class').click(function() {
 $('#menucategory').show('slow');
 return false;
  });
 // hides the slickbox on clicking the noted link
  $('a#hidecategory').click(function() {
 $('#menucategory').hide('slow');
 return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: please write the code on `jsfiddle.net`

Comment: I've taken it upon myself to code it up - [http://jsfiddle.net/xbHbP/](http://jsfiddle.net/xbHbP/1), I dont actually know what you're asking...

Comment: ahhhh do get it. Do what @Razor Storm said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your events will fire only once the DOM has loaded. Better to just hide it with CSS. Put this at the top of your page or in the stylesheet

```
#menucategory {
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the #menucateogry hidden by default via css:

```
#menucategory
{
    display:none;
}
```

Then all you need is the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $('img.menu_class').click(function() {
         $('#menucategory').show('slow');
         return false;
     });

     $('a#hidecategory').click(function() {
         $('#menucategory').hide('slow');
         return false;
  });
});
```

EDIT: The reason is, since you are doing $(document).ready(), your hide() code won't actually run until the image is done loading.

Comment: does `return false;` is necessary??

Comment: I only included the return statements since they were in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the css style element on #menucategory display:none

Answer (score 0):

first write css

```
#menucategory
{
display:none;
}
```

then write below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('img.menu_class').click(function() {
      jQuery('#menucategory').show('slow');
    });
    jQuery('a#hidecategory').click(function() {
      jQuery('#menucategory').hide('slow');
   });
```

});

Comment: Don't need `$('#menucategory').hide();` if you're using the `display:none` CSS